# Csv columns and mapping them

Tags: c#, csv

Suppose I have a csv file that contains the following:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
Supermario,1989,Nintendo
```

However I want to staticly define valid column headers such as:

```
Game_Name,Year,Console_Name
```

I would like to allow the user to map the headers in the csv to the static valid headers like so:

```
Column1 ---- Game_Name
Column2 ---- Year
Column3 ----- Console_Name
```

I am having trouble figuring out how I could accomplish this task.

I have used `csvhelper` before to read csv files but here i want to allow the user to define their own column headers, and when my form application runs I want to map them to valid column headers.

In the following section in the snippet that Jeff mentioned:

```
public MyDataClassMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.GameName).Name("Column1");
        Map(x => x.Year).Name("Column2");
        Map(x => x.ConsoleName).Name("Column3");
    }
```

Here it looks like "Column1" and the rest of them are being mapped manually not dynamically...I don't know what the columns is  going to be named so how would that work? If the columns were always named Column1, Column2, etc. etc. this would work but sometimes its Column1 sometimes its Col1 sometimes its C1 it is arbitrary.

What is a possible solution to this?

Thanks,

Comment: why dont use Column header in the first line rather than using Column1,Column2,Column3?

Comment: I am not creating the file somebody else is creating the csv file and I don't have control of it I would like the end user to be able to map it themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CsvHelper, create a class map for your data type, register it, then read it in.

```
class MyData
{
    public string GameName { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string ConsoleName { get; set; }
}

class MyDataClassMap : CsvClassMap<MyData>
{
    public MyDataClassMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.GameName).Name("Column1");
        Map(x => x.Year).Name("Column2");
        Map(x => x.ConsoleName).Name("Column3");
    }
}
```

```
public List<MyData> ReadMyData(string path)
{
    using (var file = File.OpenText(path))
    using (var reader = new CsvReader(file))
    {
        reader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MyDataClassMap>();
        return reader.GetRecords<MyData>().ToList();
    }
}
```

If you know the names of the headers may change but the column order doesn't, you could map them by index instead.

```
public MyDataClassMap()
{
    Map(x => x.GameName).Index(0);
    Map(x => x.Year).Index(1);
    Map(x => x.ConsoleName).Index(2);
}
```

Otherwise, you could add parameters to your constructor so you may provide names of the columns, then instantiate your map.

```
public MyDataClassMap(string gameNameCol, string yearCol, string consoleNameCol)
{
    Map(x => x.GameName).Name(gameNameCol);
    Map(x => x.Year).Name(yearCol);
    Map(x => x.ConsoleName).Name(consoleNameCol);
}
```

```
public List<MyData> ReadMyData(string path,
        string gameNameCol, string yearCol, string consoleNameCol)
{
    using (var file = File.OpenText(path))
    using (var reader = new CsvReader(file))
    {
        reader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(
            new MyDataClassMap(gameNameCol, yearCol, consoleNameCol));
        return reader.GetRecords<MyData>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: hypothetically if I created another entry in MyDataClassMap() called M(x=> x.Publisher).Name("Column4"); would id throw an exception if that column was not in my csv file? how could I remedy that? or is there a workaround for such a scenario

Comment: By mapping a column to a property, you're stating that the corresponding column must exist. If there's a possibility that it doesn't, you'll have to provide your own converter and check if you can read from that missing column and provide a suitable default if it doesn't.

Comment: Hi Jeff, this is great I think this would definitely be the answer I'm looking for except for the small detail that from the snippet above it doesn't look dynamic it looks like I'm still mapping Column1, Column2 etc. etc. statically I don't see how I would pass the variable headers that would allow me to do it dynamically.